# Ajax validation issue

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, post

I'm validating and posting form data via ajax with code below.

The problem is, it doesn't break  posting if during validation occured an error. Here is my code

```
var autoSaveInterval = null;
var counter = 0;

function call() {
    postViaAjax(true)
}

function postViaAjax(autosaveMode) {
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var title = $("#title").val();
    var menu = $("#menu").val();
    var parentcheck = $(".parentcheck:checked").val();
    var id = $("#id").val();
    var author_id = $("#author_id").val();
    if (parentcheck == 0) {
        var parent = parentcheck;
    } else {
        var parent = $("#parent").val();
    }
    var content = CKEDITOR.instances['content'].getData();
    content = encodeURIComponent(content);
    var dataString = 'name=' + name + '&title=' + title + '&menu=' + menu + '&parentcheck=' + parentcheck + '&id=' + id + '&parent=' + parent + '&content=' + content + '&author_id=' + author_id;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "processor/dbadd.php",
        data: dataString,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result, status, xResponse) {
            var message = result.msg;
            var err = result.err;
            var now = new Date();
            if (message != null) {
                if (autosaveMode) {
                    $('#submit_btn').attr({
                        'value': 'Yadda saxlanıldı ' + now.getHours() + ':' + now.getMinutes() + ':' + now.getSeconds()
                    });
                } else {
                    $.notifyBar({
                        cls: "success",
                        html: message + ' ' + now.getHours() + ':' + now.getMinutes() + ':' + now.getSeconds()
                    });
                }
            }
            if (err != null) {
                $.notifyBar({
                    cls: "error",
                    html: err
                });
            }
        }
    });
};



function validate() {
    var name = $("#name").val();
    if (name == "") {
        $.notifyBar({
            cls: "error",
            html: "Səhifənin qısa adını daxil edin"
        });
        return false;
    }
    var title = $("#title").val();
    if (title == "") {
        $.notifyBar({
            cls: "error",
            html: "Səhifənin geniş adını daxil edin"
        });
        return false;
    }
    var menu = $("#menu").val();
    if (menu == "") {
        $.notifyBar({
            cls: "error",
            html: "Səhifə harada yerləşəcək? Mütləq birini seçin"
        });
        return false;
    }

    var parentcheck = $(".parentcheck:checked").val();
    var parent = $("#parent").val();
    if (!$(".parentcheck").is(":checked")) {
        $.notifyBar({
            cls: "error",
            html: "Ayrıca yoxsa hansısa başlıq altında? Mütləq birini seçin"
        });

        return false;
    } else if (parentcheck == '1') {
        if (parent == '0') {
            $.notifyBar({
                cls: "error",
                html: " Parent səhifəni seçin"
            });
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.autosave').hide();
    $("#add_form").submit(function (e) {
        if (counter === 0) {
            if (validate()) {
                $('.autosave').show();
                counter++;
            }
        }
        postViaAjax(false)
        e.preventDefault();
    });


    $('#autosave').click(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            if (autoSaveInterval) {
                clearInterval(autoSaveInterval);
            }
            autoSaveInterval = window.setInterval(call, 5000);

        } else {
            $('#submit_btn').attr({
                'value': 'Yadda saxla'
            });
            if (autoSaveInterval) {
                clearInterval(autoSaveInterval);
                autoSaveInterval = null;
            }
        }
    });

});
```

How to fix that problem? I want to show only message and break posting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your "submit" function :

```
$("#add_form").submit(function (e) {
    if (counter === 0) {
        if (validate()) {
            $('.autosave').show();
            counter++;
        }
        else // Add this:
             return false;
    }
    postViaAjax(false)
    e.preventDefault();


});
```

This should help you

Comment: oh thank you very much. God Bless you. This one return made me crazy. I wask stucking in this part for a while. Please give me your contacts if you're using any IM.

Answer (score 1):

Change your "submit" function :

```
$("#add_form").submit(function (e) {
    if (counter === 0) {
        if (validate()) {
            $('.autosave').show();
            counter++;
        }
    }
    postViaAjax(false)
    e.preventDefault();

    // Add this:
    return false;
});
```

Comment: it didn't help. still i see success message directly after error message

Comment: By saying "still I see success message", you mean you are being redirected ? (or an ajax message shows up)

Comment: If you've read my js, after ajax post there is message about success, i see error message at first then success message (it measn ajax posted) and tracking whole process with firebug. Here is the scrshot http://prntscr.com/3fqm7

Answer (score 0):

other option could be to use jquery validation plugin before posting data to web server.
and use in your java script file

```
$("#Form").validate();
```

Comment: i've already written validation for my form, why to remake whole this thing if there is missing return or something else in 1 place?